# Finding $n$ given the margin of error $1$%

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am working on the following problem.

> "A CEO wants to know what proportion of the company’s employees are 
>   routinely late for work. What is the most conservative estimate of the 
>   sample size that would limit the margin of error to within 0.01 of the 
>   population proportion for a 90% confidence interval?"

This is a proportion CI so I know that the margin of error $m$ is

$$m = z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$

In this problem my understanding is that $m=.01$, $z_{\alpha/2} =1.96$ and $\hat{p}=.5$ to maximize the standard error value.

Now here is my issue, if I am not mistaken the value of $n$ must be at least 
$6766$ and I find that to be way beyond what I have expected.

Was there a mistake in calculation or assumption here?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The magic number of 1.96 is is for a 95% confidence interval, not a 90% interval.

Comment: @SeanRoberson is correct about using 1.645 instead of 1.96 for 90% CI, but it seems you did that. I also got a huge number similar to yours. For a 95% CI it would take ever more-- about 9600-- subjects to get $m = 0.01.$

Comment: Oops, I must have been dosing off while I was typing... Thanks for your help.